# TensorFlow error model.fit()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Hello learning  tensoflow and numpy. I am trying to create CNN model for images classification.

My images size is 28X28

here is my model:

```
        MODEL_NAME = 'ComputerVision-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '6conv-basic') # 6conv layer
        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.reset_default_graph()

        
        
        convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
        # layer 
        convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 28, 5, activation='relu')
        convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
        # layer 
        convnet = conv_2d(convnet, (56, 5, activation='relu')
        convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
        #layer 
        convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 112, 5, activation='relu')
        convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
        # layer 
        convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 56, 5, activation='relu')
        convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
        #layer 
        convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 28, 5, activation='relu')
        convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
        #dense layer
        convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 784, activation='relu')

        convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
        
        convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
        convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
        
 #my neural network model 
        model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')
    
    # train and test set 
    train = train_data[:-500]#my train data 
    test = train_data[-500:]
    
        X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
        Y = [i[1] for i in train]
        
        test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
        test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=10, 
    validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),  snapshot_step=200,show_metric=True,run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

when I am trying to train my model I got this error:

## it seems that the error is in Model Name

## here is the first error

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d74ffe227367> in <module>()
      4     snapshot_step=200,
      5     show_metric=True,
----> 6     run_id=MODEL_NAME)



#here is the last error it seems like I have a numpy array problem 
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `model.fit()` method using `tflearn`, the entry into the attribute `validation_set` must be a **tuple**. Try doing this:

```
model.fit(X_inputs=X, Y_targets=Y, n_epoch=10, validation_set=(test_x, test_y),\
                    snapshot_step=200, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

I hope it works!
Also, check out the [Deep Neural Network Model TFLearn docs here](http://tflearn.org/models/dnn/).